# Shorter syntax for this array insertion

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a better syntax for this array insertion in PHP? The array already has items and I'm adding items to it. I hate that I have to repeat the array name multiple times like this

```
$somearray[] = "new item 1"; 
$somearray[] = "new item 2"; 
$somearray[] = "new item 3";
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing a background. Why to ask oversimplified question instead of telling a real case? Where do you get these new values from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
array_push($somearray, "new item 1", "new item 2", "new item 3");
```

Comment: +1 Nice, didn't know `array_push()` accepted an arbitrary number of parameters `printf()`-style.

Comment: While the OP's method is still WAY readable. it is like operators in the code - horizontal positioning is a pain

Comment: @Col You can just break up the above over several lines if it's a concern. :) It greatly depends on the context though what's the most readable.

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
array_merge($somearray, array('new item 1', 'new item 2', 'new item 3'));
```